# colorButtonNormal doesn't fill entire button

Tags: android, button, material-design

I'm setting colorButtonNormal in my styles.xml like so:

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    ...
    <item name="colorButtonNormal">#33cc33</item>
</style>
```

However, the background from this attribute doesn't fill the entire space of the button.

I have two buttons. One uses colorButtonNormal and the other sets the background to the same color using android:background:

```
       <Button
            android:id="@+id/afs_login_button"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="55dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:text="Button"
            android:textColor="#FFF" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="55dp"
            android:background="#33cc33"
            android:id="@+id/guest_login"
            android:text="Button"
            android:textColor="#FFF" />
```

And the following is the result in the Android Studio preview pane:

[image]

As you can see, the blue outline is the button and the green background doesn't take up the entire space. However, if I specifically set android:background, it DOES fill the entire space. Any ideas why?

Answer (score 0):

The background drawable used with the default button is padded. The click area is bigger than the actual (visible) button size, that is what you see in the ui inspector.

Setting a color as a background will simply *fill* the whole bounds of the button, making the button *seem* bigger. The clicking area is still the same. This is because the color gets converted into a `ColorDrawable`.

You can use `tint` to change the color of the drawable—this lets you change the color, but keep the button style.

Comment: Unfortunately this yields the same result as using colorButtonNormal

Comment: @user1282637 Do you actualy want the default button to be single colored and fill the whole space like your second example?

Comment: I want it to have the same behavior as if it were using colorButtonNormal but have the color fill the background. I.e. It keeps it's selector states and ripple effect on lollipop+ (which is why I can't just use android:background)

Comment: @user1282637 You can either use the default style with the padding, *or* you can implement your own drawable using state lists. the ripple effect will be tricky, though